# nextjs " Failed to compile pages/_app.js " how to fix it

Tags: next.js

How to fix it, it happens when compiling

[image]

Comment: don't import css/scss on Footer.jsx, just remove importing line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the official document for your problem from the Next.js team:
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support

You need to import global CSS in the `_app.js` file to use it globally in your application.

For example, use Tailwind CSS as global like this:

```js
// your _app.js file
// import your CSS file you want to use globally here
import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css';

const CustomApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => (
    <Component {...pageProps} />
);

export default CustomApp;
```

If you just want to use CSS for specific components, please use `module CSS`. It will be helpful to code splitting your bundle files when you build the production version.

Example to use modular CSS just only for your component:

```js
import styles from './index.module.scss';

const YourComponent = () => {
  return <div className={styles.example}>...</div>;
};

export default YourComponent;
```

For special cases that you need to import CSS files from the library inside your `node_modules`. You can import that CSS file from `node_modules` inside your specific component.

For example:

```js
import { FC } from 'react';
import Slider from 'react-slick';

import 'react-slick/css/slick.css';
import 'react-slick/css/slick-theme.css';

const SlickSlider: FC<any> = ({ children, ...restProps }) => {
  return <Slider {...restProps}>{children}</Slider>;
};

export default SlickSlider;
```